# Optimizing deleting values from arrays that already exist on database using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algorithm, eloquent

I have an array of HTTP links, I want to clean the array and remove all values that already exist on the database (in a link field on an articles table).

Right now, I am iterating over the array, and for each value, I do query the database if the value is already present in the database.

```php
$links = array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4");

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $count = Article::where("link", $link)->count();
    if ($count) {
        // link already exists
    }
}
```

Using this approach, for an array of N links, I do perform an N query to the database in order to check for existence. Is there a way I could make this more efficient and less costly?

This task will be performed every 60 minutes and my links array may contain at least 10000 link.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a `whereIn()`? `Article::whereIn('link', $links)->exists()` would return `true` if any records in your DB have `link IN('link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4')`, or `false` otherwise

Comment: @TimLewis I would like not only to know if one of the links already exist, but I want to return all links that are not already in the table

Comment: Then you'd still run the `whereIn()` query, but do a `pluck('link')`, then you can cross-compare `$links` with the resulting array, filter/reject those that are present, and the remaining links are not in the database 

Comment: @TimLewis Got you, that's the way to go. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What will you do when you find a dup?  Remove something?  Possibly the entire action can be done in a _single_ SQL statement.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I want to remove values from the array that already exists on the table, and only keep values that are not on the table.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE ...` ?  (and have a UNIQUE constraint on it)

Comment: @RickJames  I don't want to insert anything on the database, just check if there are values on the array that already exist on the table, and remove them from the array

Comment: Perhaps you would like a single SQL statement with an `IN` clause that returns a list of missing items?

Comment: @RickJames yes exactly, and that's what the whereIn function from the Laravel Eloquent ORM does
.
.
Article::whereIn("link", $links)->pluck("links") will be translated to SQL as "SELECT links FROM articles WHERE link IN $links"
.
and then i will subtract the returned links from my original links array
.
. is this what you are referring to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have used, based on the comments of [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) and [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james):

```php
$links = array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4");

$links_already_there = Article::whereIn("link", $links)->pluck("link")->toArray();

return array_values(array_diff($links, $links_already_there));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this by using IN option.

```
    $links = array("link1", "link2", "link3", "link4");


    $count = Article::whereIn("link", $links)->count();
    if ($count) {
        // link already exists
    }
```

Comment: this will count number of links already existing and not return those links

Comment: you can use exists() function instead of count()

Comment: that will return a boolean... check my answer to the question

Comment: If you need the data simply use ->get() instead of ->count()

Answer (score 0):

This single query will return the values of `col` that are *in* the table `t` (one per row of outout:

```
SELECT  col
    FROM t
    WHERE col IN (array-of-possible-values)
```

This returns a single string -- a commalist of the values found:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(col)
    FROM t
    WHERE col IN (array-of-possible-values)
```

The resultset needs to be [somehow] put into a client 'array'.  You said you are willing to do a "diff" after that?

Comment: yes, I did implement the first query using the Laravel ORM and then I did an array_diff($original_array, $returned_values_from_sql_statement); to keep only the wanted values.